# SQL Server - How to select Monday - Sunday as varchar

Tags: sql, sql-server

How can I select and display the days monday - sunday as varchar in sql server

Comment: can you give more details please ? what is your table structure ? what is the expected result? what you already try ? Currectly we can answer `SELECT 'Monday' FROM TableName`

Comment: What do you mean "display the days . . . as varchar"?

Comment: @DonKnacki I want to be able to select this not in a row but in one column

Answer (score 0):

If you want the day of week of a date, you can use `datename()`:

```
select datename(weekday, datecol)
```